# node.js does not execute any code after serving the index.html file

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to assign a sessionId to the user when he visits the index.html page. However no code is executed after a GET request to "/" and index.html is sent as a response.

Following is the code in question

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // A unique identifier for the given session
  const sessionId = uuid.v4();
  if(req.session.uuid)
  {

  } else {
    req.session.uuid = sessionId;
  }
  console.log("Session ID : " + req.session.uuid);
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/index.html'));
})
```

Also is it good practice to explicitly send index.html file because it is sent even when the res.sendFile() call is removed.

Comment: My guess would be that you have an `express.static()` middleware handler before this that is serving the `index.html` so this code never gets to run.  `express.static()` will automatically send `index.html` if it sees a request for `/` and also sees an `index.html` file in the directory you've pointed `express.static()` at.  You could move this handler before your `express.static()` middleware.

Comment: Yes express.static() was reason why this was happening. Can you please write it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that you have an `express.static()` middleware handler before this that is serving the `index.html` so this code never gets to run.

`express.static()` will automatically send `index.html` if it sees a request for `/` and also sees an `index.html` file in the directory you've pointed `express.static()` at.

You have three options for fixing this:

1. You could move this handler before your `express.static()` middleware so it gets first crack at serving `/`.
2. You could move `index.html` to a different directory that `express.static()` is not looking at.
3. You can pass an option to `express.static(path, {index: false})` to tell it not to serve `index.html`.